# Count Rows MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[I know mysqli is the new standard and I am in the process of updating, but for now I have questions about the old standard.]

I am trying to count the number of rows that match a query, then add a number to it.

```
$findTypes = "SELECT * _products WHERE product_type = '$productType'";
$queryTypes = mysql_query($findTypes, $db_products);
$numTypes = mysql_num_rows($queryTypes);
$productID = $numTypes + 100;
```

If there is already an existing product-type in the database, then there should return a result of 101, if there are two then 102, etc.

As it stands now this doesn't work... not sure why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong, you have no `FROM` statement...

Try:

`SELECT * FROM _products WHERE product_type = '$productType'`

Comment: This did it... can't believe I overlooked that. Long day. Thanks

Comment: @Shade happens to the best of us.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could get the value from a single faster query, leaving MySQL to do all the work:

```
$findTypes = "SELECT COUNT(*) + 100 FROM _products "
           . "WHERE product_type = '$productType'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_error() function, something like

```
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

It will return error message, if your syntax is wrong.